# how to embed the whole <body> into a created new div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to wrap all Body content into a `<div>`, not including the `<body>` tag, details,

change files DOM from

```
<html>
    <body>i'm a body</body>
    <p>i'm out of body</p>
</html>
```

to (just put all inside of body into one div)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id='bodyContainer'>
            i'm a body
        </div>
        <div id='footer'>
            i'm a footer
        </div>
    </body>
    <p>i'm out of body</p>
</html>
```

I tried to make it happen by jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").append("<div id='container'>I'm a body-container</div>");
    $("body").append("<div id='footer'>i'm testing!</div>");
});
```

but failed to reform DOM as

```
<html>
    <div id='bodyContainer'>
        <body>            
            i'm a body
        </body>
       <p>i'm out of body</p>
    </div>
    <div id='footer'>
        i'm a footer
    </div>
</html>
```

this is not what I want,  please see example http://jsfiddle.net/7szM4/2/
Thanks.

Comment: Well, what you had at the jsfiddle site had an error.  It was missing the ");" at the end of it.  Once I did that, it appended it, just didn't remove the text that was already in the body or the <p></p> elements.

Comment: Wait, you want a <p> outside <body>? That's not right.

Comment: @Tudorizer - Yeah, I was confused by that too.

Comment: sorry to confuse you, a <p> outside is just a sample to show that I don't want thing goes to like .. (I updated my post, please see the last code section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('body').wrapInner('<div id="bodyContainer"/>');
    $('<div />',{id:"footer",text :"i'm a footer"})
        .insertAfter('#bodyContainer');
});
```

This should do the job, Here is the **Demo** : **http://jsfiddle.net/DeNjE/**

Comment: I think this is the right solution I want, thank a lot!
sample -> http://jsfiddle.net/4AmdV/8/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var b = $("body");
    b.text("");
    b.append("<div id='container'>I'm a body-container</div>");
    b.append("<div id='footer'>i'm testing!</div>");
});​
```

PS:- there was an error in your script on jsFiddle. Put `);` at end.

[Here is jsFiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/4AmdV/1/)

Comment: thanks, i updated the code, but not 'update' the link :) it's not a root cause to make it fail...any way, thanks

Comment: I think 'wrap' is a good point, but the 'border' shows it wraps all the <html> into the <div>, that's why I created a <p> outside for a sample.. but this is not what I want..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("body").html("<div id='container'>I'm a body container</div><div id='footer'>i'm testing</div>");
});
```

Basically use the html() function to replace all the HTML within the body.

Comment: surely I don't want to do like this, it's of bad performance.. not a DOM reform, but just only a HTML push

Comment: @Avinash @Elaine - Thanks for the feedback. I'm still learning jQuery myself, so I like to try to answer questions, but I'm not always there with the best implementation. Thanks for the correction (and good answer Avinash).